Free electron in weak periodic potential (Graphene)
I am trying to model the potential of 2-D graphene monolayer as a sum of delta functions. I don't know where to begin. Also, after defining it, I also wish to obtain the energy gap and fermi surfaces. It would be great if I am helped to define the potential. Thankyou.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

a given space which is quantized in one dimension, spaces having two large dimension, can be modelled an infinite potential well in the small dimension and zero potential along rest of the two large dimensions.
